# RESTful service issue

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wcf-rest

I am new in RESTful and WCF services and I'm making a RESTful with a JSON message format. When I run this service it gives no response.

This is my code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPersonas
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="GET",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate="getPeople")]
    Persona[] getPeople();
}

[DataContract]
public class Persona
{
    [DataMember(Name="nombre")]
    public string nombre { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="apellido")]
    public string apellido { get; set; } 

}
```

And my implementation:

```
 public Persona[] getPeople()
    {
        List<Persona> list = new List<Persona>()
        {

            new Persona(){nombre="luis",apellido="romeor"},
            new Persona(){nombre="alberto",apellido="calderton"},
            new Persona(){nombre="erick",apellido="romeor"},
            new Persona(){nombre="miguel",apellido="calderon"}

        };

        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

When I access Personas.svc/getPeople/ it gives no response. Sometimes the service opens on the service host test.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this

```
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IPersonas
  {
      [OperationContract]
      [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate="/getPeople")]
      Persona[] getPeople();
  }
```

Also use some code to test the URI, some browsers cache your request, may be thats why you don't get response always.

Comment: the same response...I think could be the end points I've not set.

Comment: Try this in web.config,
<system.web>    
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>

Comment: the same response don't know what is the problems in many tutorial that I've saw they work without problem.

Comment: Interesting, now i will go for the binding. In the "services" section have you defined like this <service name="ServiceName" ><endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IPersonas" behaviorConfiguration="RestFriendly"></endpoint></service>. Please check the contract name, it should have a fully qualified name (with namespace).

Comment: I got this response 
    <Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none">
     <Code>
     <Value>Sender</Value>
     <Subcode>
     <Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:DestinationUnreachable</Value>
     </Subcode>
     </Code>
     <Reason>
     <Text xml:lang="en-US">
     The message with To 'http://localhost:16669/Personas.svc/getPeople/' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to        an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
</Text>
</Reason>
</Fault>

Comment: Try this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b5ae495b-f5fb-4eed-ae21-2b2280d4fec3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6458/discussion-between-amar-palsapure-and-blashadow)

Comment: If your problem is not solved, add this behavior <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestFriendly">
          <webHttp></webHttp>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>